# Linq to Sql: returning limited number of rows per group

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

Imagine have a Products table with following data:

```
    ProductID    UserName   ProductName
    -----------------------------------
    1            User1      Product1
    2            User1      Product2
    3            User2      Product3
    4            User3      Product4
    5            User1      Product5
    6            User2      Product6
    7            User2      Product7
    8            User1      Product8
```

Also there is another table named UserLimit:

```
    UserName    DisplayLimit
    -------------------------
    User1       3
    User2       2
    User3       2
```

This table indicates maximum number of products that should be returned for each user.
What I want to accomplish is to have a Linq to Sql query that returns this:

```
    ProductID     UserName    ProductName
    --------------------------------------
    1             User1       Product1
    2             User1       Product2
    5             User1       Product5
    3             User2       Product3
    6             User2       Product6
    4             User3       Product4
```

Which number of products returned for each user is limited to the DisplayLimit value in UserLimit table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using grouping on user, you can easily get to each group containing the right number of products.

```
var limitedUsers = from p in dc.Products
                   group p by p.UserName into g
                   select new
                   {
                     UserName = g.Key,
                     Products = g.Take(dc.UserLimits
                                         .Where(u => u.UserName == g.Key)
                                         .Single().DisplayLimit)
                   };
```

Comment: I like this one a lot. I'd say this is actually the answer, not mine. The only change tweak I'd made is instead of subquery I'd join two tables by user name and then use the field value directly.

Comment: I like it too, it's very clean. Thanks.

Comment: Does it work with LINQ to SQL? If it does, I wonder what's the SQL equivalent of the query - it would be pretty cool if they used DENSE_RANK for implementing Take and Skip.

Comment: I mocked up a sample using your info above, so yes it works with L2S. When I iterated the resultset I noticed the SQL is executed *per user*, using a subselect in the top statement to get the number of products to return.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how link-to-sql would fit into this but if it's possible you may try to use DENSE_RANK function. For example, the query below will return last 3 projects for each user. The limit is common for all users but nothing really prevents from linking to a table with limits.

```
declare @numberOfProjects int
set @numberOfProjects = 3

;with topNProjects(userid, projectid, createdtutc, dense_rank)
as (
    select p.userid, P.ProjectId, p.CreatedDtUtc, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY P.UserId ORDER BY P.ProjectId) AS DENSE_RANK
    from DS_Project P
)
select userid, projectid, createdtutc from topNProjects
where dense_rank <= @numberOfProjects
order by projectid desc
```

EDITED: tried LINQed solution and came up with the following. I think all you will have to do is to replace my collections with references to tables in data context.

```
        Dictionary<int, string> userProjects = new Dictionary<int, string>
        {
            { 1, "User1" },
            { 2, "User1" },
            { 3, "User2" },
            { 4, "User3" },
            { 5, "User1" },
            { 6, "User2" },
            { 7, "User2" },
            { 8, "User1" },
        };
        Dictionary<string, int> limits = new Dictionary<string, int>
        {
            { "User1", 3 },
            { "User2", 2 },
            { "User3", 2 },
        };


        var ranked = 
            from up in userProjects
            join l in limits on up.Value equals l.Key
            orderby up.Value
            where (from upr in userProjects
                   where upr.Value == up.Value && upr.Key <= up.Key
                   select upr).Count() <= l.Value
            select up;
```

The result is as follows which seems is what you are looking for:

```
1, User1
2, User1
5, User1
3, User2
6, User2
4, User3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Schultz9999. This is great. But I really need the Ling to Sql query

Comment: +1 for being an awesome bit of SQL, even if it is slightly off-topic. Think I'm going to be researching this DENSE_RANK function.

Comment: @Atashbahar: I just thought you could use the same approach. LINQ has LET statement that allows defining a variable within the scope of the selection. Simple increment will create the rank as in above SQL statement and consequent subquery may select based on JOIN. I don't have time to write that down at the moment so when I am back and if it's still unanswered, I'll try.

Comment: @Schultz9999: I tried to come up with the Linq to Sql query. But no luck so far.

Comment: @Atashbahar: added LINQ solution but considering your comment for the other answer, performance of mine may not be better due to the use of Count().

Comment: Schultz9999: It works without a problem on the actual database. The issue I pointed out about the other query was due to the length of the generated query.Thanks so much.

Comment: @Atashbahar: check cpedros answer. I think it's better. I started from grouping but somehow diverged into different direction with Count(). His solution appears more efficient to me.

Answer (score 1):

If the query needs to be Linq you probably need something like this:

```
var q = tblProducts.where(p => false);
foreach (var item in tblDispLimit)
    q = q.Concat(tblProducts.where(p => p.UserName == item.UserName).Take(item.DisplayLimit));
```

Comment: @Mangus: This is great but imagine if we have a big UserLimit table (10000 rows for example) then the resulted query would be very very huge and not that efficient.